# Variable from promise remains unchanged on Bookshelf save().then()

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, bookshelf.js

I have the following code:

```
User.forge(req.body)
                .save()
                .then((model) => {
                    model.id = undefined;
                    console.log(JSON.stringify({data: model}));
                    res.json({data: model})
                })
```

which prints this into console:

```
{"data":{"name":"Test User","username":"test_usr","role_id":1,"id":54}}
```

Why it is not changing the value of model.id even on `Promise.then`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `id` you are touching is just a convenience attribute -- it is always named `id` no matter the real model id attribute name is. The model attributes, that are used by stringify, are taken from the `attributes` object within the model.

So you could just do `model.attributes.id = undefined`, but this approach is **not** recommended because it relies on Bookshelf internals.

The right approach is to use `model.set('id', undefined)` instead.